# Anypoint Platform application name missing (flowVars._clientName)

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I am facing a weird problem today, when running my MuleSoft application locally from my AnypointStudio and firing a request from postman, I am getting 403 error. When debugging I found out that the application is checking for ***flowVars._clientName***, however it is missing. According to this documentation, actually yes ***flowVars._clientName*** is expected.

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-get-the-client-application-name-in-a-flow-based-on-the-client-id-and-client-secret.

So my application fails with 403 error. Seems that other environments are working perfectly fine.

And yes it is using Client Id enforcement.

Any clues?

Comment: sorry, I was mistaken, actually clientId is fine, the issue is the applicationName is not returned. So, my variables are missing the flowVars._clientName. Yes, there is nothing wrong with authentication, but application name is not returned.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it looks like the issue is inside the logic of your application. The KB article that you referenced is a how to in case you need to obtain the client name. It doesn't say that you have to use for authentication. You don't describe how the application does authentication/authorization. Is it in a flow? Or in a policy? If it is the standard Client ID enforcement policy, the expressions to evaluate client id and secret can be configured, but I don't think the default is not `#[flowVars._clientName]` nor `#[flowVars._clientId]`.

Note that Exchange is basically a repository of APIs and other artifacts. It doesn't authenticate anything at execution time. Unless your application is trying to use it somehow, but I can't think of a reason for that.

Comment: I have added a comment on top, I will edit my question accordingly

Comment: From what I see in my application, if you have a clientId enforcement policy, the client Id does come back in a variable called #[flowVars._clientId] and the application name does come back in a variable called [flowVars._clientName].

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved only by re-downloading Anypoint Studio and mule runtime. Very weird, it was happening only for one application, not for the others. Creating a new workspace did not help, deleting the application and re-cloning and installing did not help, even recloning in a new directory did not help. Only using a new Anypoint Studio and runtime installation resolved it (even with the old code base) ...